# Spark get the actual cluster centeroids with StandardScaler

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, k-means

I have a fitted a KMeans with scaled features using StandardScaler. The issue is the cluster centeroids are also scaled. Is it possible to get the original centeroids programmatically ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler, StandardScalerModel
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

# iris data set
iris = load_iris()
iris_data = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])

iris_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(iris_data)

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=[x for x in iris_df.columns],outputCol='features')

data = assembler.transform(iris_df)

scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features", outputCol="scaledFeatures", withStd=True, withMean=False)
scalerModel = scaler.fit(data)
scaledData = scalerModel.transform(data).drop('features').withColumnRenamed('scaledFeatures', 'features')

kmeans = KMeans().setFeaturesCol("features").setPredictionCol("prediction").setK(3)
model = kmeans.fit(scaledData)
centers = model.clusterCenters()

print("Cluster Centers: ")
for center in centers:
    print(center)
```

Here I want to get the centeroids in original scale.

The centeroids are scaled.

```
[ 7.04524479  6.17347978  2.50588155  1.88127377]
[ 6.0454109   7.88294475  0.82973422  0.31972295]
[ 8.22013841  7.19671468  3.13005178  2.59685552]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `StandardScaler` with `withStd=True` and `withMean=False`. To move back to initial space you have to multiply be `std` vector:

```
[cluster * scalerModel.std  for cluster in model.clusterCenters()]
```

If `withMean` was `True` you'd use:

```
[cluster * scalerModel.std + scalerModel.mean 
    for cluster in model.clusterCenters()]
```